# try except statement error python

Tags: python, try-catch, except

```
def validnumber():
    notValid=True
    while(notValid==True):
        number=input('Enter number between 0 and 9->')
        if number=='':
            print('Empty input!')
        else:
            try:
                number=int(number)

            except ValueError:
                print('Number not an int value!Try Again!')
            else:
                if number>=0 and number<=9:
                    notvalid=False
    return number

def main():
    myvalidnumber=validnumber()
    print(myvalidnumber)

main()
```

Hey guys. I wrote this program and just had 1 question.

-> the program does not end even if i enter a number between 0 and 9. Could anyone explain why is this happening?.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there is one orphan `else:` in your code after `except`

Comment: Actually, you can have an `else` with `try-except`.

Comment: orphan else: ? So it wouldn't work if there was an else inside an else?

Comment: Check the second `else` with wrong variable `notvalid` that would be `notValid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's variables are case sensitive. `notvalid` is not the same as `notValid`. So, when you say

```
notvalid=False
```

you are creating a new variable. Just change it to

```
notValid = False
```

and you are fine.

Comment: Fantastic. You are absolutely right. I make sure to remember this but miss here and there. Thank you!

Comment: @vishal use a good editor like Sublime text or something. They autocomplete the variable names.

Comment: @thefourtheye: let's not start an editor war here :)

Comment: @JayanthKoushik That was just a suggestion, I am not trying to sell sublime ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye will definitely look into it. New to python. THANK YOU!

Comment: @vishal Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: i would but it says i gotta wait!

Answer (score 0):

You already got the solution from thefourtheye. Just for the record: the canonical way to implement such a function in Python is to use an infinite loop and either a `break` statement or an early `return` (as in the example below). Also proper use of the `continue` statement can simplify the flow:

```
def validnumber():
    while True:
        number=input('Enter number between 0 and 9->')
        if number=='':
            print('Empty input!')
            continue

        try:
            number=int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print('Number not an int value! Try Again!')
            continue

        if number < 0 or number > 9:
           print('Number not between 0 and 9! Try Again!')
           continue

        return number
```